# Android's SharedPreference.putString() replaces '\r' to '\n' in strings

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've strange issue in my android app. I'm saving some string in `SharedPreferences` using `putString` and load it using `getString`. However i've found that all '\r' are replaced with '\n' in string while saving and it leads to app issue. Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Shared preference is a structre that runs some parsing algorithm and holds an encoded text file with datas inside. Probably your datas are being corrupted with these algorithms.

The workaround solution can be replace your "\r" with "\r" or "\(unicode)".

Good luck there

Comment: i know it saves data in XML files but i expect it to save/load without changes. in fact it introduces it's own logics which leads to issues

Comment: Too bad that cause the bad problem. The problem could be cause of formatting xml file. Did you try \\n?